# Replace a keyword+value with a string infront and behind the value

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby, in a string I want to replace

```
something...
specialstring=360256
something...
```

with

```
something...
<script src="https://gist.github.com/someuser/360256.js"></script>
something...
```

I believe it can be done with a Regex (maybe gsub), but I am afraid I am just not that proficient.

Edit: "something... " indicates text that should not be changed. I want to replace all instances of

```
specialstring=10000
```

with the below in the string (extract the number)

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/someuser/10000.js"></script>
```

Where 10000 can be any number terminated by a newline.

Comment: Which part will always be in the input string - `something` or `specialstring=360256`? Ideally, can you provide more examples of input and output?

Comment: specialstring=360256 is the element to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ input = %|something...
▷ specialstring=360256
▷ something...|
#⇒ "something...\nspecialstring=360256\nsomething..."
▶ out_tmpl = '<script src="https://gist.github.com/someuser/%{tmpl}.js"></script>'
▶ puts input.gsub(/^specialstring=(.*)$/) { out_tmpl % { tmpl: $1.strip }}
#⇒ something...
#  <script src=\"https://gist.github.com/someuser/360256.js\"></script>
#  something...
```

This is more-or-less generic solution, that parses input for occurrences of `specialstring=ANYTHING`, and then, using string formatting, injects this `ANYTHING` into the template, substituting the original pattern.

Comment: Thankyou, you were the only one who understood the question before I edited it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, that is not great and you probably should try to state questions more precise.

Comment: Hey, thankyou for letting me know. I changed the title and question to reflect that I wanted to extract a value and to use it to replace a substring. Do you feel I can improve the question further?

Comment: Since we are all building a knowledge base for future readers, and especially taking into account that your edits were done after the answer was accepted, I would remove all these “Edit:“ annotations; but the main point was: whether you want, say, the value to be extracted and reused, this is to be mentioned explicitly. The main advise would be: _please, be as explicit as possible_.

Answer (score 0):

Not a ruby expert myself but I'll give it a shot.

If `something...` is your search patter and want to replace whatever's in between, use this as matching regex for replacement:

```
/(?<=something\.\.\.)[\s\r\n]*(.+?)[\s\r\n]*(?=something\.\.\.)/
```

If, however , `specialstring=360256` is what you look for and want to replace it, as per the other answer this is your regex:

```
/specialstring=360256/
```

Both tested with http://rubular.com/

**Update 1**

Right, got it now:

```
"something­...\nspeci­alstring=3­60256\nsom­ething..."­.gsub(/spe­cialstring­=(\d+)/, '<script src="­https://gist.githu­b.com/some­user/\1.js­"></script­>')
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is not, you are closer with the second one. I want to extract the number (360256) and put it in the second text. I don't know how to do that.

    <script src="https://gist.github.com/someuser/putthenumberhere.js"></script>